# The problem is that I want to make the line waves have a color gradient only without making the background color gradient

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I just want the color of the vector lines to have a gradient color without changing the background color

```css
.wave {
  --c: red;
  /* Color */
  --t: 5px;
  /* Thickness */
  --h: 50px;
  /* Height  */
  --w: 120px;
  /* Width  */
  --p: 13px;
  /* adjust this to correct the position when changing the other values*/
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: calc(var(--w)*4);
  height: calc(var(--h) + 10px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wave:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% calc(100% + var(--p)), transparent 47%, var(--c) 50% calc(50% + var(--t)), transparent calc(52% + var(--t))), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% calc(0% - var(--p)), transparent 47%, var(--c) 50% calc(50% + var(--t)), transparent calc(52% + var(--t)));
  background-size: var(--w) var(--h);
  background-position: calc(var(--w)/2) calc(-1*(var(--h)/2)), 0px calc(var(--h)/2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-origin: content-box;
  animation: move 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wave" style="--w: 21px;--h: 6px;--p: 6px;--t: 5px;--c: #BEA036;transform: matrix(-0.99, -0.16, -0.16, 0.99, 0, 0);"></div>
  <div class="wave" style="--w: 21px;--h: 6px;--p: 6px;--t: 5px;--c: #BEA036;transform: matrix(-0.99, -0.16, -0.16, 0.99, 0, 0);"></div>
  <div class="wave" style="--w: 21px;--h: 6px;--p: 6px;--t: 5px;--c: #BEA036;transform: matrix(-0.99, -0.16, -0.16, 0.99, 0, 0);"></div>

</div>
```

As shown in the pictures
[image]

Make the wave lines gradient in color like the image below

[image]